# Is there an event generated for declined teams calls in CSharp Graph Communications Calling SDK?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

The microsoft graph communications api sends webhook callbacks for various events related to calls, for example, when a participant joins and leaves, a webhook is generated.  When utilizing the CSharp Graph Communications Calling SDK (https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/index.html), a corresponding event is generated if the appropriate callback is registered (ICommunicationsClient.Calls()[callid].Participants.OnUpdated).  There is also a callback that may be registered to listen for call update events (ICommunicationsClient.Calls()[callid].OnUpdated).  I have registered for both of these events.

It is possible for the bot to join a teams meeting, and then invite a user into the meeting via a dial-out.  In this case, the user may accept and join the meeting, or decline the invitation.  If the user accepts and joins the meeting, I see the participant join webhook as well as the corresponding sdk event callback.  Likewise, when a participant later leaves the meeting.  However, for a decline, I see the webhook, but no event callback is generated.

If a user declines a meeting invitation, a webhook is also generated.  The data in this webhook is of the following form:

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotifications",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.commsNotification",
            "changeType": "deleted",
            "resource": "/app/calls/<callid-guid>/operations/<opid-guid>",
            "resourceData": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.inviteParticipantsOperation",
                "clientContext": "<client-context-guid>",
                "id": "<id-guid>",
                "participants": [
                    {
                        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.invitationParticipantInfo",
                        "identity": {
                            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identitySet",
                            "user": {
                                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.identity",
                                "id": "<user-guid>",
                                "tenantId": "<tenantid-guid>"
                            }
                        },
                        "participantId": "<participant-id-guid>"
                    }
                ],
                "resultInfo": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.resultInfo",
                    "code": 603,
                    "message": "addParticipants failed for participant 8:orgid:<user-guid>. Underlying reason: Decline. DiagCode: 603#0.@",
                    "subcode": 0
                },
                "status": "failed"
            },
            "resourceUrl": "/communications/calls/<callid-guid>/operations/<opid-guid>"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I am not able to determine if the csharp sdk exposes this webhook as an event.  It is not documented, nor is the code available for determining how I can get informed of this event.  Is there an event that gets generated in the sdk for this webhook?  And if so, how do I register for this event?

I have tried looking through the sdk methods in the various documented classes as well as checking to see if the existing callbacks are invoked in response to this webhook.  I was unable to make any progress in doing so.

thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seems to be any event generated for declined teams calls in CSharp Graph Communications Calling SDK.

If you wish you can suggest this feature here: [Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)